# How many memorys can a process have under PPC64 on linux

Tags: c, linux, memory, linux-kernel, powerpc

I watched a testcase for linux. it test for `mmap` like follows:

```
#define HIGH_ADDR       (void *)(0x1000000000000)
addr = mmap(HIGH_ADDR, map_sz, PROT_READ,
                MAP_SHARED | MAP_FIXED, fildes, 0);
```

In that case under **PPC64**, the **Expected results** is get an errno `ENOMEM`.
But **Actual results** under **PPC64** is get an errno `Invalid argument`.
Anyway, it works well on **X86_64 arch**.
I think maybe the PPC64 haven't assigned enough memory. So, I try to modify the `HIGH_ADDR`'s define to:
`#define HIGH_ADDR       (void *)(0x7FFFFFFFFFF)`
But it still get `Invalid argument`.
I just want to konw, How the linux for PPC64 manage his memory. I mean, I want to know the userspace program's memory geography. Or what's the MAX address Should I use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man 2 mmap`:

```
       EINVAL We don't like addr, length, or offset (e.g., they are too large,
              or not aligned on a page boundary).

       EINVAL (since Linux 2.6.12) length was 0.

       EINVAL flags  contained neither MAP_PRIVATE or MAP_SHARED, or contained
              both of these values.
```

So `mmap` will signal an error with `EINVAL` if `addr` is too large.  This is therefore expected behavior.

**Recommendation:** Don't use `MAP_FIXED`, unless you have a really good reason.

**Footnote:** Not all 64-bit architectures support 64-bit addresses.

Comment: Hi, Epp. This code is only for test memory alloc (also test the mmap system call). It's part of Linux-test-project. I think the MAP_FIXED may be need for test? I can't find the MAX addr that I can mmaped. I only find that PPC64 provide from 0x0 to 0x7FFFFFFFFFF for User program(64bit).    Thank you.   :)

Comment: You don't need `MAP_FIXED` to allocate memory (in fact, it's a bad idea, see R's answer).  Why do you need to know the maximum address?  I can think of reasons, but they're rather esoteric.

Comment: Because this code is used for test for that if the kernel can map file to "high_addr". It's just for testing but not for daily using.   :)

Comment: Also I have read the part of man page about mmap. I still think that I need this flag.     Sorry.   Anyway, thank you very very much~

Answer (score 2):

Using `MAP_FIXED` like this is invalid. Even if it worked, it would potentially map over top of something you don't want to clobber, like a loaded shared library or the dynamic linker. The only safe way to use `MAP_FIXED` is to map over top of address ranges already assigned to your program (e.g. by a prior call to `mmap` without `MAP_FIXED`).

Comment: Hi, R. This code is only for test memory alloc (also test the mmap system call). It's part of Linux-test-project. I think the MAP_FIXED may be need for test? Also I will try to run it again after I remove that flag. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi, R. I read the man page for mmap. And think the flag-MAP_FIXED can't be removed in this case.    :-(

Comment: What is the test trying to assert? I'm nearly certain that whatever it's trying to do is wrong.